# How to show $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{t}\frac{1}{i}2^{t-i}=2^t\ln 2 -\frac{1}{2}\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{2^k(k+t+1)}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis, taylor-expansion, closed-form

How to show the below equation ?

$$\sum\limits_{i=1}^{t}\frac{1}{i}2^{t-i}=2^t\ln 2 -\frac{1}{2}\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{2^k(k+t+1)} 
~~~~~(t\in \mathbb Z^+)$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One may write

$$
\begin{align}
\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{2^k(k+t+1)}&=\sum\limits_{i=t+1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^{i-t-1}i}\qquad (i=k+t+1)\\\\
&=\sum\limits_{i=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^{i-t-1}i}-\sum\limits_{i=1}^t \frac{1}{2^{i-t-1}i}\\\\
&=2^{t+1}\sum\limits_{i=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^{i}i}-2^{t+1}\sum\limits_{i=1}^t \frac{1}{2^ii}\\\\
&=2^{t+1}\ln 2-2^{t+1}\sum\limits_{i=1}^t \frac{1}{2^ii},
\end{align}
$$ then divide by two, where we have used the classic Taylor expansion
$$
-\ln (1-x)=\sum\limits_{i=1}^\infty \frac{x^i}{i},\quad |x|<1.
$$